# Sessions are not saved in database sessions table in Laravel 5.5 on shared hosting server Godaddy

Tags: php, laravel, session, shared-hosting

I hosted laravel app using Godaddy's shared hosting .

Im using `SESSION_DRIVER=database` , it is proper working in my local system XAMPP , and is saves sessions in database sessions table

but on shared hosting server, My laravel app unable to save sessions using database and file both type. so user failed to redirect after login.

after searching ...i added 2 lines in `php.ini` file :

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
session.save_path = "/tmp/"
```

after this I m able to save session in tmp folder and redirect after login.

but I want sessions to be stored in sessions table .

I have searched and got this like session_set_save_handler

http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

if laravel is unable to store sessions in database on shared hosting server , how to fix this ?  please help me.

Comment: Are you sure your database connection works properly? Sometimes, on a shared host, the application uses another environment file, like on Amazon Beanstalk

Comment: @RobanReuvers , yes my database connection is properly works